# java fx printing simple form document

Tags: java, javafx

i'm writing simple application in Java Fx which main ability is to print form which i've created in scene builder (some labels plus textfields which can be fill by user and PRINT button in the bottom of page). Do you have any ideas how can i write something like this?I read about PrinterJob class but i'm not sure how to use it properly.Maybe there are better ways to achieve my goal?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already said PrinterJob is the starting place of JavaFX printing. Just follow the documentation:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/print/PrinterJob.html

And here are a few more examples:

http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=javafx.print.PrinterJob